# How do i add a pageView to my flutter main.dart code?

Tags: layout, dart, flutter

My app runs perfectly on my device, however, on the log messages, I get an error that suggests that a pageView is needed.
[This is the error I get when I swipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KFZo.png).
So I was hoping someone could help me sort out these errors I keep getting every time I swipe on my device

```
   void main()
   {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]) 
       .then((_) {
            runApp(new MyApp());
      });
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget 
    {
              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context)
              {

                final tabController = new DefaultTabController(
                    length: 4 ,
                    child: new Scaffold(
                      appBar: new AppBar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
                        title: new Text("Discover Zambia"),
                        bottom: new TabBar(
                            indicatorColor: Colors.red,
                            indicatorWeight: 4.0,
                            tabs: [
                            new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.home),text: "Home"),
                            new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.landscape),text: "Sights"),
                            new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.local_drink),text: "Nightlife"),
                            new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.restaurant),text: "Foods")

                        ]),
                      ),
                      body: new TabBarView(
                          children: [
                            new Home(),
                            new Sights(),
                            new Nightlife(),
                            new Foods()
                          ]
                      ),
                    ));
                return new MaterialApp(
                  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                  title: "",
                  home: tabController,

                );
              }

      }
```

Comment: Look this: https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-pageview-in-flutter-with-custom-transitions-581d9ea6dded . I think it will help you to implement pageview in your app.

Comment: I think it's a problem in your TabBarView children. Because when I run your code by simply changing the TabBarView elements with containers, it works correctly.